# Spring batch version 2.1.5 concurrent issue in BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper class

Tags: spring-batch

I am using Spring batch 2.1.5 as it is compatible with Spring 3.0.3 that we are using in our project. We are getting error while executing the batch job "Duplicate match with distance <= 5 found for this property in input keys" and this looks like a concurrency issue with class BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper. I check this thread "http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/102370-duplicate-match-with-distance-5-found-for-this-property-in-input-keys" that says there is concurrency issue that has resolved in Spring batch 2.1.8.I have tested my code with Spring batch 2.1.8 and I am not getting the concurrency issue and data is persisted correctly. I can not use Spring batch 2.1.8 as it is internally using Spring 3.0.5 version and I don't wanted to have any class loading issue if I upgrade with 2.1.8. 
Is there any workaround with Spring batch 2.1.5 to overcome the concurrency issue?

Thanks
Sach

Comment: It would surprise me if Spring Batch 2.1.8 didn't work with Spring 3.0.3.  Have you tried doing the upgrade?

Comment: 2.1.8 is working with Spring 3.0.3 but hopefully I dont get any classnot found issues in future if I upgrade it with 2.1.8.